# Specify at function declaration that it should be applied to invidual arguments

Tags: matlab

Is it possible in Matlab to specify at function declaration that this specific function is to be applied to indiviual arguments (as opposed to vectors)? An if so, what about anonymous functions?

What I mean is, instead of writing something like

```
f = @(x, y) x.^2+2*x.*y.^2-x./(y.^3)...
```

One might be able to write something like

```
f = .@(x, y) x^2+2*x*y^2-x/y^3
```

This would help a lot light-headed people like me who tend to forget dots.

Sorry if it's a duplicate, I searched but as you can see I have trouble putting it in clear words so I cannot find an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not sure if that does the trick for you, but you can but an arrayfun inside the anonymous function like:

```
f = @(x,y) x.^2+2*x.*y.^2-x./(y.^3);    
g = @(x,y) arrayfun(@(A,B) A^2+2*A*B^2-A/B^3 ,x,y) %for matrix output
h = @(x,y) arrayfun(@(A,B) A^2+2*A*B^2-A/B^3 ,x,y,'UniformOutput',false); % for cell output
```

with A being an element of x and B being an element of y

Comment: That should do the trick, thanks a lot! Could you explain what the different arguments of arrayfun are, especially the last ones?

Comment: The first part is the function; x and y being the vectors; and after that the  option 'UniformOutput' ist set to false. Its in this case not necessary. if you leave it out the output is a matrix which might be even more useful for you. if you set it to false the output will be a cell array that allows you to handle multiple outputs better. I usually take that option so i dont have to think about the type that i want to handle, but that might be just my personal oppinion